# how to delete data from 2 tables using same query?

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables Patient, Individual
Both has some common data, I want to delete record from both tables.
What I have tried so far is:

```
delete p,i from #patient p
inner join #individual i on i.patientUid=p.patientUid
where p.patientuid='test id'
```

Error:Incorrect syntax near ','.

:(

Comment: Googling didn't even take much time than posting the question.

Comment: you are using brent ozar image haha

Answer (score 1):

You need two statements, one for each table.

For example:

```
delete p from #patient p
inner join #individual i on i.patientUid=p.patientUid
where p.patientuid='test id'

delete i from #individual i
inner join #patient p on i.patientUid=p.patientUid
where p.patientuid='test id'
```